# Live Variable analysis to calculate Def and Use set for basic block

Tags: compiler-construction

For the basic block,  calculate use and def set for live variable analysis.
example of the basic block B1.

```
input j;
t1 = j % 2;
t1 ! = 0 goto L2
```

I have calculated two answers:

1. `Def = {j, t1}, Use={}`
2. `Def = {j, t1}, Use={j}`

Which of the following is correct? If none, then what would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the names suggest for def and use sets, the `Def` set means you are killing all definitions of variables for a particular block, and `Use` means you are using some variables to do your calculation. Refer to the below image for a clear understanding ([Nielson's book chapter 2 slides](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Ehrni/PPA/slides2.pdf)).
[image]

Now, if we consider your example and will give labels to each line in the basic block then your code would look like below

```
input j;   /*label 1*/
t1 = j % 2; /*label 2*/
t1 ! = 0 goto L2 /*label 3*/
```

and your def and use sets would be

```
label | Def | Use
  1   |  j  |  ∅   --> ∅ is empty set
  2   |  t1 |  j   --> as all definitions of t1 is killed, uses variable j 
  3   |  ∅  | t1
```

Information on [kill/Gen sets](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15745-s03/public/lectures/L4_handouts.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In terminology I am used to 1 is the correct answer. The Use set of the block is the set of variables where the first occurance in the block is a use. In this example there are no such variables as the first occurance of both `j` and `t2` updates the variable. The Def set on the other hand is the set of variables that are updated in the block, and in this case both `j` and `t2` are updated.

Comment: Yes, the first one is correct because, before there usage both the variables are defined.